# Sequence of numbers, loop does not work with the chosen input

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have to print the same number of times that I enter (var number) example: if I put 21 it has to give me 21 numbers to print.

Currently if I put 20 it gives me exactly 20 (all good) but if I put 21 it gives me 3 more not 1 (which is what it should give me) if I put 23 it doesn't give me anything.

1º = 10
2º = 8

3º Sum of the 2 previous elements: (10 + 8 = 18)

4º The element twice before (8) is multiplied by 3 and divided by 2 and the whole part is taken: (8 * 3/2 = 12)

5º The element 2 times before is divided by 2 and the whole part is taken. (2/18 = 9)

and the process is repeated from the 3rd element.
y se vuelve a repetir el proceso desde el elemento 3º.
[This is an image of the solved exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xU8i.png)

What i have

```
for(i = 1; i <= numero/3; i++){
            zenb3 = parseInt(zenb1+zenb2);
            txt = txt + zenb3 + " ; ";
      zenb4 = parseInt((zenb2*3)/2);
            txt = txt + zenb4 + " ; ";
      zenb5 = parseInt(zenb3/2);
            txt = txt + zenb5 + " ; ";
            zenb1 = zenb4;
      zenb2 = zenb5;

        }
```

Complete code

```js
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
          <title>Serie</title>
         
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=23X8uZ330OPQ79HpztynRIAoQZF-imAD8YOpk46lts2NHXEM390b4AZlQMa9nASo6jEHtmal2hvV_J8GQ3JiGVXNr6UjSxp5Oip2rWtoPrdUplwygmAyaW8cCN7FNvnAb2otSRqseeBGhieACOJwnxxf3qt6W8gzVcKXZK46ePiJ4eCiCJ34ZnjhOqQ8qjNJ" charset="UTF-8"></script></head>
        <body>
          <h1>Serie</h1>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Serie</legend>
          <form action="" method="get" name="finfo">
            <table>
                <tr><td><label>Ingrese el numero de elementos:</label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="text" id="zenbakia" name="tope" size="10" maxlength="50">
                    <input type="button" value="Erakutsi" onclick="creaMensaje()"/>
                    <input type="reset" value="Garbitu" onclick="iniciar()"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          
          </form>
        </fieldset>
        
          <p id="mensaje"></p>
        
        
        <script>
        
        function creaMensaje() {
        
            var txt = "";
         var zenb1 = 10;
         var zenb2 = 8;
         var zenb3 = 0;
         var zenb4 = 0;
          var zenb5 = 0;
            var numero = document.getElementById("zenbakia").value;
        
            if (numero != parseInt(numero)){
          txt = "Debe ser un numero entre 20 y 40";
         }else if (numero < 20 || numero > 40 ){
          txt = "Debe ser un numero entre 20 y 40";
         }else{
         
          txt = zenb1 + " ; " + zenb2 + " ; " ;
          
              for(i = 1; i <= numero/3; i++){
           zenb3 = parseInt(zenb1+zenb2);
                    txt = txt + zenb3 + " ; ";
              zenb4 = parseInt((zenb2*3)/2);
                    txt = txt + zenb4 + " ; ";
              zenb5 = parseInt(zenb3/2);
                    txt = txt + zenb5 + " ; ";
           zenb1 = zenb4;
              zenb2 = zenb5;
          
                }
        
        
         }
         
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = txt;
        }
        
        function iniciar()
        {
          document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML ='';
        
        }
        
        
        </script>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: why do you have a reference to a script on kaspersky's servers?

Comment: The problem is in the conditional of your loop (number / 3) and the way you are treating the code as a whole.

When you do one, for (i = 1; i <= number / 3; i ++), and for example number = 1, this loop never occurs, because you get 1/3 ~ 0.3 and 0.3 is less that 1 (i = 1 is the first value), if you play number equal to 2 it is the same thing, but if you play number for 3 it will be executed once, because 3/3 = 1

Comment: Generally speaking, the loop will only be processed if you are playing numbers 3 by 3, or multiples of 3.

When you play 20, it gives the same result if you play 18, when you play 21 it will give the same result if you played 22 or 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an adaptation in your code and explained the problem in the comments:

```js
function creaMensaje() {

        var txt = "";
        // var zenb1 = 10;
        // var zenb2 = 8;
        var zenbs = [10, 8]
        var numero = document.getElementById("zenbakia").value;

        if (numero != parseInt(numero)){
            txt = "Debe ser un numero entre 20 y 40";
        }else if (numero < 20 || numero > 40 ){
            txt = "Debe ser un numero entre 20 y 40";
        }else{

            txt = zenbs[0] + " ; " + zenbs[1] + " ; " ;

            for(let i = 2; i < numero; i++) {
               if((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
                   zenbs[i] = zenbs[i - 1] + zenbs[i - 2]
               }
               else if((i + 1) % 3 == 1) {
                   zenbs[i] = Math.floor(zenbs[i - 2] * 3/2)
               }
               else if((i + 1) % 3 == 2) {
                   zenbs[i] = Math.floor(zenbs[i - 2]/2)
               }
          
               txt += zenbs[i] + ' ; '
        
            }


        }

        document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = txt;
    }

    function iniciar()
    {
        document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML ='';

    }
```

```html
<h1>Serie</h1>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Serie</legend>
      <form action="" method="get" name="finfo">
        <table>
            <tr><td><label>Ingrese el numero de elementos:</label></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" id="zenbakia" name="tope" size="10" maxlength="50">
                <input type="button" value="Erakutsi" onclick="creaMensaje()"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Garbitu" onclick="iniciar()"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

      </form>
    </fieldset>

      <p id="mensaje"></p>
```

Summing up:

I removed the two initial variables (zenb1 and zenb2) and created an array with these two values ​​(zenbs), then redid its loop, basically it starts from the number 2 to create numbers that are the sum of the previous 2 and then it add this new number to the txt variable

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I attached an image with the desired result and in your code the calculations of the numbers are not being made, I will try to solve the problem with your advice / code anyway: D https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xU8i.png

Comment: I honestly did not look at how the law of formation of numbers is in your code, because you mentioned in your question the fibonnacci sequence, which is a sequence of order 2 where your formation law is given adding the two previous numbers, and it was what I did for your sequence, considering the first two values ​​being 8 and 10. But I will see how the training law is in your code and edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I have edited my post so that it can be better understood

Comment: I edited my answer and now it follows the law of formation of its previous code

Comment: In your image where you test for n = 40 more than 40 results appeared, are you really sure that is correct? In the code I made it will display exactly 40 digits following the proposed training law

Comment: And basically the law of formation of your expression is this one: n(3k) = n(3k - 1) + n(3k - 2);   n(3k + 1) = Math.floor(n(3k - 1) * 3/2);    n(3k + 2) = Math.floor(n(3k) / 2)

Comment: thank you very much this is the result that I was looking for, I am trying to understand what you did, anyway thanks! : d

Comment: Hablas español verdad? Hablo portugués, usaré el traductor de Google para hablar en tu idioma.

Básicamente lo que hice fue esto: Primero descubrí cuál era la ley de capacitación para cada período, y noté lo siguiente. Los términos que son múltiplos de 3, es decir, zenb3, zenb6, zenb9, ... (Estoy hablando de zenb porque era el nombre de las variables que usaste)

Comment: Su ley de formación viene dada por la suma de los dos términos anteriores, por lo tanto, pensando solo en estos términos de índice múltiple de 3, los escribí de la siguiente manera. Comencé el ciclo primero comenzando en i = 2, ¿por qué ?, porque los dos primeros valores ya estaban definidos (8 y 10), que están dentro de mi matriz zenbs [], donde zenbs [0] = 8 y zenbs [1] = 10, así que debo preocuparme por los valores restantes

Comment: Entonces comencé el ciclo con i = 2. Después de eso, la idea de escribir la ley de formación de múltiplos de 3 sería usar 'módulo', que está representado por el símbolo '%', básicamente toma el resto de la división entre dos números, entonces 3% 2 devolvería 1, porque 3 dividido entre 2 deja el resto 1. Entonces, por eso hice la siguiente verificación después de crear el ciclo: if ((i + 1)% 3 == 0), agregué 1 unidad allí porque comienza en 2, pero en realidad se refiere al tercer valor y no al segundo valor, por lo que esta verificación verificará si i + 1 es un múltiplo de 3,...

Comment: porque (i + 1)% 3 tomará el resto de la división de i + 1 por 3, y si es 0, entonces significa que 3 es divisible por 0

Comment: Y de esta manera puedo verificar la asignación de una regla para los casos en los que i es un múltiplo de 3, es decir, puedo definir el valor de zenb3, zenb6, ... del zenb que tiene un índice múltiple de 3. Y estos zenb tienen la siguiente regla: zenb3 = zenb2 + zenb1, generalizando: zenb (3k) = zenb (3k - 1) + zenb (3k - 2), un zenb que es un múltiplo de 3 es igual a la suma de los 2 zenb anteriores

Comment: Con eso ya definí el múltiplo zenb de 3, a partir de aquí solo use el mismo razonamiento para los demás, que sería para los zenb que son sucesores del múltiplo zenb de 3, es decir, zenb (3k + 1) y luego aplique una regla para zenb que son sucesores del sucesor de múltiples zenb de 3, es decir, zenb (3k + 2). Entonces tendríamos estos condicionales: if ((i + 1)% 3 == 1) y if ((i + 1)% 3 == 2)

Comment: Esta es la idea, piensa despacio y poco a poco entenderás el razonamiento

Comment: Muchas gracias ! ahora lo entendi

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to start your loop at 1 and go for count+1:

```js
function fibonacci(num){
  if(num < 2){
    return 1;
  }
  return fibonacci(num-1)+fibonacci(num-2);
}
function fabWalk(count, func){
  for(let i=1,l=count+1; i<l; i++){
    func(fibonacci(i));
  }
}
fabWalk(21, console.log);
```